# How to serve S3 data via Cloud Front only to specified authorized users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have multiple users for my website that is hosted on AWS. These are not AWS users but subscribers of my website. Each user can see data for which they are authorized.The data is stored on AWS S3 and is served through CloudFront.

I would like to limit access to the resources to authorized users and still use cloud front to serve data. One resource can be accessed by multiple users.

I tried using Signed URL's but if the user shares this URL with some unauthorized user he/she will be able to see the data as the URL is already signed.

How can I enable this kind of access control with S3/Cloud Front?

Comment: *I tried using Signed URL's but if the user shares this URL with some unauthorized user he/she will be able to see the data as the URL is already signed.*  Well, if the user shares their password with another user, the same thing is true.  Or if the user takes the file they downloaded from you and emails it to another user...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable signed cookies in CloudFront:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cloudfront-signed-cookies-for-private-content/